# why am I getting this error in deployiing my maven basen web application on tomcat server:-

Tags: deployment, maven-plugin, tomcat7-maven-plugin

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:deploy (default-cli) on project KuchNewWeb: Tomcat return http status error: 403, Reason Phrase: : <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

[ERROR]     You are not authorized to view this page.